# Display Image on Mouseover (inside working example with jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/22sxotje/ where if I mouseover element with class `lochtonialcaress` then the image `lochtonialcaress.png` appears.

How can I change this script to show the image *(classname.png)* of any elements with *classname*, but show nothing if there no image `classname.png`

It's work if i copy it and change only classname, but how to join it together:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var yOff = 15;
    var xOff = -20;
    var pathToImage = "http://x.jupe.pl/lochtonialcaress.png";

    $(".lochtonialcaress").hover(function (e) {
        $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    },

    function () {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text").remove();
    });

    $(".lochtonialcaress").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    var yOff = 15;
    var xOff = -20;
    var pathToImage = "http://x.jupe.pl/vollsprotector.png";

    $(".vollsprotector").hover(function (e) {
        $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    },

    function () {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text").remove();
    });

    $(".vollsprotector").mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#image-when-hovering-text")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is my paragraph with a <a class="lochtonialcaress" href="#">very special hover</a> effect on the link.</p>
<p><span class="vollsprotector">Lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirm od tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>The hovering works with every element that has <span class="no-image"> a class of <em>"text-hover-image"</em></span>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @haxxxton I try do it without jquery but then i find this jsfiddle and its almost what i need but I'm know nothing about jquery also my knowledge about javascript is not to impressive and i dont know how to bit this jquery example :(

Answer (score 0):

You will find an working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22sxotje/3/).
you just need to add an `if` statement to do it.

```
$(".lochtonialcaress").hover(function (e) {
    if (pathToImage) {
    $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
    $("#image-when-hovering-text")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
        .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");
    }
},
```

instead of:

```
$(".lochtonialcaress").hover(function (e) {
    $("body").append("<p id='image-when-hovering-text'><img src='" + pathToImage + "'/></p>");
    $("#image-when-hovering-text")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("top", (e.pageY - yOff) + "px")
        .css("left", (e.pageX + xOff) + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");
},
```

Comment: @Florian this change nothig? I probably need to know how to give to this funcion parameter with clasname and also check if file exist with given classname

Comment: "How can I change this script to show the image (classname.png) of any elements with classname, but show nothing if there no image classname.png" in my example if pathToImage is null, I don't show the image. like you ask in your question, doesn't you?